# Register dataset in AzureML Python SDK v2 from a dataframe

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk, azuremlsdk

I am looking to upgrade to the new Azure AML Python SDK v2.

However, I can't replicate registering a dataset (now called data assets) directly from a dataframe. it seems that now the only option is to create a data asset from saved files (either local or adls).

In the SDK v1, I was just using [Dataset.Tabular.register_pandas_dataframe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.data.dataset_factory.tabulardatasetfactory?view=azure-ml-py#azureml-data-dataset-factory-tabulardatasetfactory-register-pandas-dataframe)

```
from azureml.core import Dataset

dataset = Dataset.Tabular.register_pandas_dataframe(
    dataframe=dataframe,
    target=target,
    name=name,
)
```

The documentation I found about the topic:
[Create a data asset: Table type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-data-assets?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=python#create-a-data-asset-table-type)
[Create a tabular dataset/data asset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/migrate-to-v2-assets-data?view=azureml-api-2#create-a-tabular-datasetdata-asset)

Is there any way to register the dataset without having to store the parquet files in local?

I was thinking about writing the parquet files in adls and create a dataset from those files. However, I can't find on their documentation how to do so.

I have tried to upload the parquet files as:

```
adls_url = f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net"

# Connect to the Azure blob service
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(
        account_url=adls_url,
        credential=credential
    )
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(
    container_name
)

# Prep data for saving
data = pd.DataFrame.to_parquet(df)

# Upload the dataframe to ADLS
container_client.upload_blob(
    output_path,
    data,
    overwrite=True,
    encoding='utf-8'
)
```

This works if I upload a csv. As a parquet I get:
ResourceExistsError: The requested operation is not allowed in the current state of the entity.

Anyway, that would look like a workaround.

I guess as a last resort, I could still use azureml.core.Dataset. [They do not recommend using v1 and v2 together](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-migrate-from-v1?view=azureml-api-2#using-v1-and-v2-code-together), but there is [backwards compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-migrate-from-v1?view=azureml-api-2#data-datasets-in-v1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python SDK v2, below are the inputs you can use to register a dataset.

| Location | Examples |
| --- | --- |
| A path on your local computer | ./home/username/data/my_data |
| A path on a Datastore | azureml://datastores/<data_store_name>/paths/ |
| A path on a public http(s) server | https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pandas-dev/pandas/main/doc/data/titanic.csv |
| A path on Azure Storage | (Blob) wasbs://@.blob.core.windows.net/<path_to_data>/ (ADLS gen2) abfss://<file_system>@<account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/ (ADLS gen1) adl://.azuredatalakestore.net/<path_to_data>/ |

With one of the below asset types.

| type | API |
| --- | --- |
| File Reference a single file | uri_file |
| Folder Reference a folder | uri_folder |
| Table Reference a data table | mltable |

So you need to save somewhere and register by using above ways.

My idea here is to save the pandas dataframe to a parquet file in the datastore, which is a storage account associated with your ML workspace, and use that Azure datastore path to register.

First, create a datastore in your ML workspace mounted to the `azureml` container.

[image]

Next, get the credentials of the storage account associated with your ML workspace and use the code below to save the parquet file in the above container.

`jgsai4079545193` is my storage account.

```
df.to_parquet("abfs://azureml@jgsai4079545193.dfs.core.windows.net/mldata/mydata.parquet", storage_options={"connection_string":conn_str})
```

If you have different credentials, refer to this [documentation](https://github.com/fsspec/adlfs) and use appropriate `storage_options`.

This will create a parquet file inside the `mldata` folder.

[image]

Now, register this data by giving this path and the datastore mounted to the `azureml` container.

```
VERSION = "1"

path = "azureml://datastores/data_store_name/paths/mldata/"

my_data = Data(
    path=path,
    type=AssetTypes.URI_FOLDER,
    description="<ADD A DESCRIPTION HERE>",
    name="Parquet_data",
    version=VERSION,
)

dataref = ml_client.data.create_or_update(my_data)
```

The data asset is now registered.

[image]

To consume, use the code below.

```
data_asset = ml_client.data.get("Parquet_data", version="1")

path = {
  'folder': data_asset.path
}

tbl = mltable.from_parquet_files(paths=[path])
df = tbl.to_pandas_dataframe()
print(df)
```

Output:

|  | Name | Age | City | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Alice | 25 | New York | 60000 |
| 1 | Bob | 30 | San Francisco | 80000 |
| 2 | Charlie | 22 | Los Angeles | 55000 |
| 3 | David | 35 | Seattle | 90000 |
| 4 | Eva | 28 | Chicago | 70000 |

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It actually works. 
Functionality is a bit different though. It will create a file called mydata.parquet. Whereas registering a dataset in v1 creates a folder with a random string and inside creates the parquet partitions.